# purrr - pmap - Supplying different column names to function parameter names in tidy style

Tags: r, purrr, rlang, tidyeval

I'm wondering if there's a way to specify which columns should be matched to which arguments when calling `pmap` on a `data.frame` or named list.

The default behaviour, which is useful and intuititive in most contexts is to match column names to argument names, as in

```r
check_row_deidentified <- function(encntr_key, clinical_event_key, note_value, ...) { 
  # Do stuff
  tibble::tibble(encntr_key, clinical_event_key, note_value)
}

notes_1 <- tibble::tibble(
  encntr_key = c(1,2,3),
  clinical_event_key = c(1,2,3),
  note_value = c("foo", "bar", "baz")
  ) 


out <- notes_1 %>%
 purrr::pmap_dfr(check_row_deidentified)
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to give an input with different column names, and specify how pmap should treat those.

As in:

```r
check_row_deidentified <- function(encntr_key, clinical_event_key, note_value, ...) { 
  # Do stuff
}

notes_1 <- tibble::tibble(
  key_enc = c(1,2,3),
  key_clinical = c(1,2,3),
  free_text = c("foo", "bar", "baz")
  ) 


out <- notes_1 %>%
 purrr::pmap_dfr(check_row_deidentified, encntr_key = key_enc, clinical_event_key = key_clinical, note_value = note_value)
```

I guess an obvious choice would be to just rename those columns before I call `pmap`, as in

```r
# Given as arg
to_rename <- rlang::exprs(
  note_value = free_text,
  encntr_key = key_enc,
  clinical_event_key = key_clinical
)

notes_1 %>%
  dplyr::rename(!!!to_rename) %>%
  purrr::pmap_dfr(check_row_deidentified)
```

But I'm not sure if something less cludgey exists

Comment: My examples don't actually do anything, @akrun , maybe it would be better to give a trivial return, as `check_row_deidentified` just returns null. 

**EDIT:** Less trivial now

Comment: You could also use anonymous function call without bothering about the names .e. `~ ..1` or ~ ..1 * ..2`

Comment: @akrun I don't think I'm any happier with a positional solution, they usually feel even more brittle to me than those that rely on named elements- 

I've just gone ahead and implemented my "cludgey" workaround, which honestly isn't that cludgey really.

Comment: Note that `rename()` supports strings as well, e.g. `rename(!!!chr_vector)`. I wouldn't use expressions to rename a data frame with a known mapping of names.

Answer (score 1):

I decided that my "cludgey" workaround is good enough for this excercise:

> I guess an obvious choice would be to just rename those columns before I call `pmap`, as in
>
> ```r
> # Given as arg
> to_rename <- rlang::exprs(
>   note_value = free_text,
>   encntr_key = key_enc,
>   clinical_event_key = key_clinical
> )
>
> notes_1 %>%
>   dplyr::rename(!!!to_rename) %>%
>   purrr::pmap_dfr(check_row_deidentified)
> ```
>
> But I'm not sure if something less cludgey exists